# Why do I get an error when export using Auto Rig Pro addon and a failure to create an Export?

Tags: export, add-on, error, auto-rig-pro

Running the newest version of both Auto Rig Pro and Blender, I've tried a reinstall of both blender and the addons Auto Rig Pro and still run into the export attempt error.

The model is fully weighted and rigged but I'm still having the same issue even if I change a lot of different settings, the bones are setup for UE4 Legacy but I had this issue with UE5 bone setup as well, if anyone has any ideas on what's wrong let me know, I've tried everything I can.

[image: Error message upon Export attempt]